# How to make online compilers to ignore debug statements in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging

I am using these lines of code for debugging my C++ program.

```
    void dbg_out(){cerr << endl;}
    template<typename Head, typename... Tail> void dbg_out(Head H, Tail... T) { cerr << ' ' << H; dbg_out(T...); }
    #define dbg(...) cerr << "(" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "):", dbg_out(__VA_ARGS__)
```

But the problem with this is that when I am using dbg function and submit on an online judge like codeforces or codechef it is increasing execution of code. Is there a way to make the online compiler to ignore the debug statements ?

Comment: `#if 0` is the fairly standard way to disable code

Comment: Just replace `#define dbg(...) cerr << "(" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "):", dbg_out(__VA_ARGS__)` by `#define dbg(...)`?

Comment: Enclose the code in an `#ifdef WHATEVER`, and when you want to log, compile with `-DWHATEVER`?

Comment: Why not remove all debug logging and just run your code locally with a debugger attached. Then just post the code to the competitive site. Another option is to write some unit tests locally and use them to verify parts of your code are correct. These (debugging/unit testing) are good skills to develop as a software devolper anyway. And they tend to help with delivering cleaner code.

Comment: Notice that you can simplify `dbg_out` to:`template<typename... Ts> void dbg_out(Ts... args) { ((std::cerr << ' ' << args), ...); std::cerr << std::endl;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the preprocessor conditionally define the macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_LOG
  #define dbg(...) std::cerr << "(" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "):", dbg_out(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
  #define dbg(...)
#endif
```

Now if you compile with the option `-DDEBUG_LOG`, the log would be sent to `std::cerr`. An online judge wouldn't add that command line option, but you can [locally](https://godbolt.org/z/oqEdf3z9r).